# help in seleting nodes inputs through xml path

Tags: xml, xpath, cucumber, webrat

I have a form with checkboxes, each with a span with some text describing the selection, for isntance:

```
          <input name="people[]" value="953580619" type="checkbox">
          <span>Fake person 1</span>
```

I want to select those checkboxes which have a following span with the word "Fake" appearing in them. How do I select only these checkboxes which have a following::span with the word Fake in them, and no other?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With XPath (since this question had an XPath tag)

```
//input[following::span[1][contains(., 'Fake')]]
```

This selects `<input>` elements which are directly followed by `<span>` that contains the string "Fake". Replace the `//` in that XPath expression with steps matching your document structure, if possible.

Comment: I would also add a predicate to narrow it to "checkbox" inputs only. Something like `//input[@type='checkbox'][contains(following-sibling::span[1],'Fake')]`

Answer (score 1):

You should use a label tag:

```
<input id="person_953580619" name="people[]" value="953580619" type="checkbox">
<span><label for="person_953580619">Fake person 1</label></span>
```

Then you can do:

```
page.check('Fake person 1')
```